# How to do order by date in mysql without sorting the values alphabetically on same date?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

This is my mysql query:

```
SELECT date, ledger_id, did, particulars, invoice_id, invoice_amount,
       disocunt, product_return, cash_amount 
FROM ledger where did='$did' 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

I get the following output:

> 30-03-2017    bKash
>       30-03-2017  Invoice

As a result, after ordering by date, it is sorting the data alphabetical order. However, I need the data same as it is in database. I mean I just need to fetch the data ordered by date, and no change in alphabetical order. How can I do that?

Comment: ` order by date ASC, ID ASC` guessing you have a field called ID. you basically sort on 2 fields

Comment: i am using ORDER BY date ASC only here

Comment: Can we assume that you have an auto incrementing id on your table? and if so what is it?

Comment: so add another field for the order

Comment: adding another field for order worked for now. Have to check with larger amount of outputs. thanks brother.

Comment: @Augwa, yes, ledger_id is auto incremented

Comment: So date (assuming it's a datetime field) is a fairly unique value, kind of hard to sort by two unique values, unless you want whichever was first when the datetime is the same. if it's purely a date field then it's an easy fix, `ORDER BY date ASC, ledger_id ASC`

Comment: Solved this way. Thanks a lot